# How can I convert a float list into an int list of pairs in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The task is to convert `[1.5, 1.2, 2.4, 2.6, 3.0, 3.3]` into `[(2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 3)]`

Currently I use a bruteforce way to do it:

```
result = []
for i in range(0, len(nums), 2):
   x = int(round(nums[i]))
   y = int(round(nums[i + 1]))
   result.append((x,y))
return result
```

Is there a more concise built in solution (e.g., using `itertoools`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe, but you could just `zip` `lst[::2]` and `lst[1::2]`

Comment: Also, there's nothing wrong with the way you're doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` them together (using the alternating patterns `[::2]` and `[1::2]`) and then round as you go:

```
L = [1.5, 1.2, 2.4, 2.6, 3.0, 3.3]
L = [(round(x), round(y)) for x, y in zip(L[::2], L[1::2])]
# [(2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `iter()` with `zip()` to create pairs. And later you can round values.

I will use code from @Alex answer to show difference

```
L = [1.5, 1.2, 2.4, 2.6, 3.0, 3.3]
it = iter(L)
L = [(round(x), round(y)) for x, y in zip(it, it)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the given list is always made of even number of elements:

```
l = [1.5, 1.2, 2.4, 2.6, 3.0, 3.3]

def f(s):
    for i in range(int(len(s)/2)):
        yield (round(s[2*i]), round(s[2*i+1]))

print(list(f(l)))

#[(2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution using zip. You can try this too.

```
l = [1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5,6.6]
def fun(l):
    x = list(zip(*[l[i::2] for i in range(2)]))
    print(x)

ll = round[(x) for x in l]
fun(ll)

#[(1, 2), (3, 4), (6, 7)]
```